# RegSetValueEx throws error char * is incompatible with LPCWSTR

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

There is a function that copies a value to registry using

```
RegSetValueEx(hKey, theName, 0, REG_DWORD, (unsigned char *)&value, sizeof(value));
```

`theName` passed by the caller is a `char *`

I get a compile error:

> Argument of type `char *` is incompatible with LPCWSTR

Why do I get this error?

I have copied some code that uses it (and I know it builds succesfully) and built it myself.

Has the function changed or my project settings is messed up?  I do not know which version of VS the code was created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because Windows has been a Unicode operating system for the past 18 years.  Its default string type is utf-16 encoded, wchar_t* in your code.  Or std::wstring.  Or LPCWSTR, the typedef used in the Windows headers.  Note the prevalence of 'w', it means Wide.

It still supports char* strings, you have to use RegSetValueExA().  Note the added "A".  It is also a project setting to make your program use the old multi-byte API.  Project + Properties, General, Character Set.  Avoid marketing to the other 5 billion customers when you do.

Comment: Yes, I change the character set to `Not Set` and got rid of the error.So if I use the `RegSetValueEx` (without the `A` you say) and character set to none, the only problem is the language?No other problems right?

Comment: There is no way I'm going to tell you that you won't have problems.  Read the link.